# Аналог IFrame

Tags: html, iframe, javascript

Друзья! Нужна ваша помощь. Необходимо реализовать следующее:
Веб страничка (А) с элементами управления в левом сайдбаре. Все остальное пространство занимает окно в другой сайт (Б). Элементы управления должны взаимодействовать с сайтом в окне. Сайт Б - некий сторонний сайт, редактирование которого невозможно, также в хедере сайта Б прописано "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: sameorigin", стало быть IFrame не подходит. Так же еще одно условие - сайт Б не должен проксироваться сервером, а взаимодействовать напрямую с клиентом.
Подойдут любые решения, главное - чтобы со стороны клиента не требовалось установки никакого дополнительного ПО.
Есть идеи?

Comment: Какого характера взаимодействие предполагается?

Comment: Нажатие кнопок, заполнение форм.

Comment: Взаимодействие страниц возможно только на одном домене (касается как iframe, так и ajax).

Comment: Я думаю, нужно посмотреть как примерно это делает surfingbird. Либо получать код сайта и помещать в нужные тебе элемент. Естественно целевой сайт останется нетронутым в данном случае.